# Using Google search API from the browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, search

Are there any good client-side JS libraries for accessing Google's search API?

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice example how to use [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/getting_started#data-json) on client side.
From the docs:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON/Atom Custom Search API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function hndlr(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // in production code, item.htmlTitle should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.htmlTitle;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=cars&callback=hndlr">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You have to define your API Key as

> YOUR-KEY

and your query term like the

> q=cars

parameter in the script src attribute and the results will be loaded into the "content" div by the definied javascript function "hndlr()" that is the callback function from the Google API.

Comment: Changed KEY and tried, still getting "bad reguest"? any idea ?

Comment: Where can I get `API-KEY`?

Comment: From the "Google Developers Console" https://console.cloud.google.com

Answer (score 0):

try google search API https://developers.google.com/web-search/